# How to retweet a tweet in iphone app?

Tags: twitter

hy i am using twitter api to get feeds/tweets of any user now i want to retweet a tweet so kindly help me that how can i retweet it in a same way as twitter official retweet.
I haven't used MGTwitterEngine yet how to integrate it in my app or tell me some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ReTweet Intent` https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#retweet-intent

Example: https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=221635702067167232